# using spring.contextPath=/xyz redirect to every controller mapping properly

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redirect, url-mapping

I have my url: *http://abcd/*
I added **server.contextPath=/whitelist** in application.properties file.
I want my code to run successfully on http://abcd/whitelist

As by default "/" root is added, my url *http://abcd/whitelist/* is working fine and giving me the home page as desired but after clicking the "upload data" button on home page, url should redirect to  *http://abcd/whitelist/upload*.

But it's redirecting to *http://abcd/upload* which is not accessible and showing me application not available error.

I have

**1. /**

**2. /upload**

**3. /home**

mapping in my controller class.

And i want them all to work properly with proper url.

I have tried adding "@RequestMapping", it didn't work.

I have also tried adding "@RestController", that also not help.

Below is my controller class.

---

```
@SpringBootApplication

//@RestController

//@Configuration

@Controller

    public class FileUploadController {
        private static final String filename = "application.properties";

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return "home";
        }
        @GetMapping("/upload")
        public String upload() {
            return "upload";
        }
        @GetMapping("/home")
        public String home() {
            return "home";
        }
```

---

### Below is my home page home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
<title>Vodacom</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="css/styles.css"   rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"   rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body align="center">
<div class="container-fluid" >
<h1>Whitelistloader</h1>

<div class="mainBlock" style="border: solid 1px black;">
<h2>Whitelist Actions</h2><br />
<a href="/addWhiteList" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Whitelist Single Number</a>
<a href="/upload" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Upload CSV file to be uploaded</a>
<a href="/searchMSISDN" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Search for MSISDN</a> <br /><br />       
</div>
<!-- h2>Number Encryption Check</h2><br />
<a href="/encryptNumber" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Encrypt Msisdn to Long Number</a -->
</div>
</body>
```

**I want my url http://abcd/whitelist to work for mentioned mapping with proper functionality**

Comment: We need to see the code from you webpage, how are you making your call

Comment: `home page as desired but after clicking the "add number" button on home page` what homepage are you talking about and where is that code?

Comment: So sorry @ThomasAndolf     I entered wrong , I just edited my question please have a look again. And help me out

Comment: where is that code, where is the homepage code, i want to see how your rest call is made.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAndolf I have uploaded my home.html as well on the query. Please go through once and provide the needy changes. I hope this is what you were asking for.